# Which RPC implementation does rpcbind apply to?

Tags: onc-rpc

As indicated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call#Analogues, there are many implementations of RPC.

Which RPC implementation does [`rpcbind`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/rpcbind/index.html) apply to? I am using Lubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: Classifying are opinion-based, already said about concept categories, not gonna say it again.

Comment: The page you reference has a link to the Unix RPC implementation; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call - I'm not sure what else you're asking for

Comment: @StephenHarris Thanks. There are many other implementations of RPC, and that is why I am not sure.

Comment: Hah I just noticed that you *tagged* your own question with the answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Wikipedia `rpcbind` page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/rpcbind) mentions that it is part of Sun RPC, or [Open Network Computing RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call) as it’s now known.

`rpcbind` provides a service registry for ONC RPC. Programs providing ONC RPC services register themselves with `rpcbind`, and programs trying to use ONC RPC services can ask `rpcbind` what services it know about and how to reach them. All RPC implementations have some sort of service registry, but it doesn’t necessarily appear as a specific program: it can be built in to the RPC stack, or handled externally (*e.g.* using some variant of DNS).